# How these measures have more note values than mentioned in the time signature

Tags: time-signatures, tuplet

I'm trying to play this piece of music where the time signature is 4-4 but it seems that the measures have more note values. How is this possible? Can someone please explain?
I have attached a photo of first six measures.
Thanks a lot ❤

[image]

Comment: Looks like the start of a transcription of "He's a Pirate" from the Pirates of the Caribbean movies. I'm personally prone to taking this back to sender and asking for a version in 12/8 time.